# WAMP Server will not allow access to website using "www"

Tags: apache, webserver, wamp, wampserver

I cannot access my website using "www" before domain name but I can if I don't use the "www". I would like to have both accessible.

I am very familiar using Apache2 Server on Linux but it's not often I have to use it alongside WAMP. I have done plenty of messing around in the config files and have tried a few different methods but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wherehousemke.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/wherehousemke"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/wherehousemke/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The website that I am trying to get this to work for is http://wherehousemke.com. That URL is working but if you add "www" in there It will NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a DNS record that redirects from your TLD to the www subdomain https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/using-cname-for-www-redirection